# Apparently assignment to proprierty of object does not work in javascript

Tags: javascript

Firs of all, I am newbie with Javascript and I think it is from about two hours that I am trying to understand this issue.

I have some objects (nested to one other object) where one property (called years) have this value: `"1972-1974"`, for example. The value may change, but what remains the same is the presence of `-`. Object that have this property (year) with the value `-` need to be replicated, changing only year. If the value is `"1972-1974"` I want three object with value `1972`, `1973` and `1974` in the year property (other property does not change).

Example of data structure.

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
        "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
},
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "years": "1972-1974",
         }
    },
```

This is my attempt to solve my requiriment:

```
function formatYears(data) {
    data.forEach(
        function(d, index) {
            if(typeof d.properties.years === "string" && d.properties.years.includes("-")) {
                var temp = d.properties.years.split("-");
                var count = temp[temp.length - 1] - temp[0]; 
                d.properties.years = parseInt(temp[0]);
                for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    var newData = jQuery.extend({}, d);
                    newData.properties.years = parseInt(temp[0]) + i + 1;
                    data.push(newData);
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

I call this function with

```
formatYears(json.features);
```

where `json` store all data previusly loaded.

I do not know why but all new objects have as years property `1974`, in our example.
I tried to debug it and `newData.properties.years` take the right value (1973 and then 1974), but `newData` after `data.push(newData)` does not hold 1973 and 1974, but always 1974.

**UPDATE**:

Add [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxzhljsVh6zoYXdNVVl3ZkI4a1k/view?usp=sharing) to json.

**UPDATE 2:** 
Solved.

```
function formatYears(data) {
    data.forEach(
        function(d, index) {
            if(typeof d.properties.years === "string" && d.properties.years.includes("-")) {
                var temp = d.properties.years.split("-");
                var count = temp[temp.length - 1] - temp[0]; 
                d.properties.years = parseInt(temp[0]);
                for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    var newData = jQuery.extend(true, {}, d);
                    newData.properties.years = parseInt(temp[0]) + i + 1;
                    data.push(newData);
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Why?

Comment: You aren't accessing the `features` array in your data where the `year` property is. ex: `newData.features[0].properties.years`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek He is calling the function with json.features so that should not be a problem.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek so with `newData.properties.years` what am I changing?

Comment: @lezan You are adding a new property `year` with the `properties` that contains `name`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I am inspecting object obtain and I cannot see any other `years`. Just one property `years` with 1974. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
function formatYears(data) {
    data.forEach(
        function(d, index) {
            if(typeof d.properties.years === "string" && d.properties.years.includes("-")) {
                var temp = d.properties.years.split("-");
                var count = temp[temp.length - 1] - temp[0]; 
                d.properties.years = parseInt(temp[0]);
                for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    var newData = jQuery.extend(true, {}, d);
                    newData.properties.years = parseInt(temp[0]) + i + 1;
                    data.push(newData);
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple `for` loop:

```
function formatYears(features) {
  features.forEach(function(feature){
    var fromto = feature.properties.years.split('-');
    var years = [];
    for (var y = +fromto[0]; y <= fromto[1]; ++y)
      years.push(y);
    feature.properties.years = years;
    return years;
  });
}
```

```js
var f = [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "years": "1972-1974",
         }
    },
     {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "years": "1975-1978",
         }
    }];



function formatYears(features) {
  features.forEach(function(feature){
    var fromto = feature.properties.years.split('-');
    var years = [];
    for (var y = +fromto[0]; y <= fromto[1]; ++y)
      years.push(y);
    feature.properties.years = years;
  });
}

formatYears(f)

console.log(f.map(f => f.properties.years))
```

Comment: As is does not work as I want (for example some yars are `NaN`. I am trying to understand what this code do. Update: thjs code does not anything to original data or am I missing something?

Comment: Hm, it should replace original `feature.properties.years` by array. Let me test it :)

Comment: Try it now, I mistyped loop incrementation variable as `i`.

Comment: If you get `NaN`s here, add this data sample to question, please. May be it's some `years: 'non-numeric'`

Comment: I change previously `i` with `y`. I will try now with other two change that you did.

Comment: Same. This code does not add any object. Then, if years is "x-y" it change `feature[0]` to `x` and if years is "x" put it at `NaN`.

Comment: you have literally `x-y` years??  Then you just need to check `fromto[0]` and `fromto[1]` are numeric. Isn't it obvious?

Comment: Maybe it is, but I cannot achieve that. Where is (or are) error(s) in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to your js code

```
   function formatYears(data) {
    var out = [];
    data.forEach(
        function(d, index) {
            if(typeof d.properties.years === "string" && d.properties.years.includes("-")) {
                var temp = d.properties.years.split("-");
                var count = (parseInt(temp[1],10) - parseInt(temp[0],10)) + 1; 

                //d.properties.years = parseInt(temp[0]);
                for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    var newData = jQuery.extend(true, {}, d);
                    newData.properties.years = parseInt(temp[0], 10) + i;
                    console.log(newData);
                    out.push(newData);
                }
            }
        }
    )
   console.log(out);
}
```

and when I am calling this with a data like this

```
 var data = {
    "features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "years": "1972-1974",
         }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "years": "2007-2008",
         }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "years": "2010-2011",
         }
    }

    ]
};
```

its working fine.

Comment: Not here.  Two 1972 and one 1974 with "1972-1974" and with "2007-2008" return two 2007 and with "2010-2011" return two 2010.

Comment: Can you please share the data that you are using.

Comment: I am uploading it.

Comment: Now the function turn years like "1972-1974" to "1972", always the first one year of strings, but it does not add new object with 1973 and 1974. Update: added link to data on request.

Comment: Actually we are not adding no one object to the original object(data). As is, code work as before the last edit. Why we are pushing `newData` into `out`?

Comment: Into `out` I have all objects that previously had `years` like "1972-1974". For example, `object[0].years = 1972, object[1].years = 1973 and object[2].years = 1974`.

Comment: So now the out array satisfies your requirement?

Comment: Nope. I do not want a new array of object, but I wanna put the new object in the same array. By the way, adding `true` to `var newData = jQuery.extend(**true,** {}, d);` fix the problem.